# Blender 2.8 Scripting for a simple button

Tags: scripting

i was trying script a button in 2.8 i stared withe the templates UI panel

but i wanted to place in the top bar which error out if i change the layout
is there any way to place the button in the top bar?[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Pre or Append to the header.**

With all panels and headers in blender you can append or prepend a draw method to them.

[image]

Test script prepends a splash screen button to topbar

```
import bpy

def draw(self, context):
    self.layout.operator("wm.splash")

bpy.types.TOPBAR_HT_upper_bar.prepend(draw)
```

To find the class to "leach" onto, with developer extras on, right click and view source. With the naming convention, `TOPBAR` pretty self explanatory, `HT` it's a header type. *Hence using autocomplete in python console is a way to find contenders*

Comment: thanks i'll try and see if it works